# Redondear numeros

Tags: javascript

Genero numero aleatorios los cuales quiero redondearlos a multiplos de 10.

**es decir:**

si tengo un numero 7. se redondearia a 10

si tengo 11. se redondearia a 10

si tengo 18 se redondearia a 20.

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  let n = Math.random() * 100 / 5;
  console.log(n);
}, 500);
```

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022488/

Answer (score 1):

Divide entre 10, redondea y luego multiplica por 10.

```js
var case1 = 11;
var case2 = 18;

function redondear10(entrada) {
  return Math.round(entrada / 10) * 10;
}

console.info(redondear10(case1));
console.info(redondear10(case2));
```